# understanding helper function to store object data for dynamic state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, object

Just say my  state was repeatitive as such:

```
state = {
customer: {
  name: {
    elementType: "input",
    elementConfig: {
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "Your Name"
    },
    value: ""
  },
  street: {
    elementType: "input",
    elementConfig: {
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "Street"
    },
    value: ""
  },
```

And I wanted to store the object data into a helper function so that I could add zip code, country, and so on so forth and not have my state be cluttered. Would your helper Function look like this? I am having trouble figuring out how to write such a function

```
 const helperFunction = function({elementType, ElementConfig, type, placeholder, value}){
    setState({elementType: 'some value', ElementConfig: {type: "", placeholder: ""}})
 }

so I can call state = {
    name: helperFunction()
}
```

I guess I really don't know how to write it but I want to show my thought process. I am sure it is easier than this. I am just new to coding. If someone could help me or link me to an article that would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: For a call like `name: helperFunction()` to work, that function needs to return an object, not call setState. Also, you're probably going to be calling something like `helperFunction("input", "text", "country")`, right? What is the end goal here? Are you trying to build a form?

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah I am trying to build a form with name, street, zip code, country and use a switch statement to check input type and then render the correct HTML element.  But more so curious on understanding how to make a helper function that holds an object data and how to target the data dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and what you want behavior to be then I think you could either use a *reference* object with the shape you want and "default" values and copy, or create the utility function which would do the same but allow for some "configurability". If you are setting your initial state, either in a constructor or in the body, you can't call `this.setState`.

```
const referenceObject = {
  elementType: "input",
  elementConfig: {
    type: "text",
    placeholder: "",
  },
  value: "",
};
```

Then when you are declaring state shallow copy the reference object

```
state = {
  name: { ...referenceObject },
};
```

If you are looking for a utility function to do this ***and*** set some values then one example could look as such.

```
const helperFunction = ({ elementConfig, ...config }) => ({
  ...referenceObject,
  ...config,
  elementConfig: {
    ...referenceObject.elementConfig,
    ...elementConfig,
  }
});
```

The idea being you shallow copy each level of nesting and apply the override/new value.

Initialize state with what you want to override

```
state = {
  name: helperFunction({
    elementConfig: { placeholder: 'Placeholder' },
  }),
};
```

```js
const referenceObject = {
  elementType: "input",
  elementConfig: {
    type: "text",
    placeholder: "",
  },
  value: "",
};

const helperFunction = ({
  elementConfig,
  ...config
}) => ({
  ...referenceObject,
  ...config,
  elementConfig: {
    ...referenceObject.elementConfig,
    ...elementConfig,
  }
});

const state1 = {
  name: { ...referenceObject
  },
};
console.log(state1);

const state2 = {
  name: helperFunction({
    elementConfig: {
      placeholder: 'My Custom Placeholder'
    }
  }),
};
console.log(state2);
```